# Single-community detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, social-networking, igraph, graph-theory, modularity

Here is a presentation of my dataset :

- Large social-network composed of Twitter accounts followers of very large related accounts, followers of this followers, and followers of these followers, at every iteration cleaned for bot accounts, private-accounts, etc.
- Total nodes : around 500,000
- Total connections : 95 millions
- 4 nodes have more than 3 millions connections
- 567 nodes have more than 100,000 connections
- Half of the dataset have 3 or less connections

This said, **I want to clean this network in order to get the "best" single-community coming out of the raw initial** graph before further clustering in sub communities. Keep in mind these few facts:

- Due to the way the data is collected, I know there is One Large Community common to most of these nodes that is more optimal than the whole network.
- I would like to get an optimal single sub-network of the initial network, getting rid of all the nodes that don't belong to the largest possible common-community.
- Further study will constitute in splitting this community in several communities, following the general community-detection literature, but this is not what I want to do here.

I have used community-detection algorithms such as louvain or modularity-optimization (in a smaller subsample for the too computational second one), but the goals of these algos are to have the best split, while my goal in some ways is to have the best merge.

**The main problema can be summarized by this idea:** *I was considering using the following algo. Starting with the large network ; removing the "weakest" node at every iteration ; while the modularity of the whole improves.*  But this will lead to a very tiny community at the end.

Do you have any directions where to look for ? A way to change the methodology of an existing algo ? Or even a paper that is related to this issue even if pretty different ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into clique detection/optimization algorithms?

Comment: It really depends what you mean by "best single community." Modularity can be a useful measure, but it doesn't always match with exactly what you're trying to do. I would play around with the algorithm you discussed -- remove the edge with the lowest betweenness every iteration -- but don't necessarily go until modularity is maximized.

Comment: @Alejandro This is the idea of the kind of result I would like to meet. But the problem is that due to the high concentration of the graph, maximum clique would lead to a very small subcomunity. I would like to get something much larger with a better representativeness. But thanks, that's the spirit

Comment: A flow algorithm might also be interesting... if you can already label a couple important nodes in your community, work out from them rather than in from the unimportant nodes. Assign each of these nodes a certain amount of "fluid" and allow it to flow evenly for a few iterations. Remove all of the nodes that don't end up with some minimal amount of fluid (which is a parameter you'll have to choose.)

Comment: @rogaos, thanks, but since this needs to be part of an academic paper at some point, I would like to have some sort of quantitatively measured optimality in the decision of stopping the edge removing loop.

Comment: @ylnor you're going to have to choose *some* parameterization... (your choice of optimality measure is just another one.) You can always choose several and write about the differences. There's nothing wrong with making decisions like this in an academic paper, as long as you're honest about them. Grading community structure in a graph is an open problem, since there's no ground truth, and I would read any paper that stated that it filtered to the "best single community" with significant skepticism.

Comment: @rogaos, thanks, to the very little I just red, a flow-algorithm definitely sounds like an interesting approach I had not considered yet. It seems like it has disappeared in the recent literature on community detection though (most of the papers dates back to 03/04), do you have any idea why? I'll implement it and and post here my first results.

Comment: you might find useful the ModuLand method family. considering you have quite a big network, use the C binaries, not the cytoscape plugin. moduland will give affinities between nodes and modules. then you can set a threshold to define your core module. also its hierarchic nature might help you to split further the core module. http://www.linkgroup.hu/modules.php

Comment: also, without providing at least example data, you can not expect proper answers, but only helpful comments. you have only one network with a unique topology. how do you estimate the confidence of your result? do you have a set of nodes you know that they belong to the core community?

Comment: @deenes, thanks for the helpful comment. I'll take a look at ModuLand. There is no implementation in Python yet, right? I might be available to provide a sample of the network, but It'll probably lack representativeness.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try several approaches. The size of your network is challenging, not all community detection methods are capable to run in reasonable time on such a large network. You could try those methods which have adjustable parameters, and empirically find out how these parameters affect their resolution. At certain values you can expect the core network covered by one cluster. For example there are the `walktrap` and `spinglass` method in igraph. If you change the number of steps at walktrap, you can observe a change in the size of the largest community:

```
g <- barabasi.game(n = 10000, m = 2)

steps <- seq(1, 10, 1)
steps <- c(steps, seq(11, 200, 10))
w <- list()
ccount <- NULL
clargest <- NULL

for(s in steps){
    cat(paste('Running walktrap with steps =', s, '\n'))
    w0 <- walktrap.community(g, steps = s)
    ccount <- c(ccount, length(levels(as.factor(w0$membership))))
    clargest <- c(clargest, max(tapply(w0$membership, w0$membership, length)))
    w[[s]] <- w0
}

plot(ccount ~ steps,
    xlab = 'Number of steps',
    ylab = 'Number of communities',
    main = 'Walktrap with increasing number of steps')
plot(clargest ~ steps,
    xlab = 'Number of steps',
    ylab = 'Size of largest community',
    main = 'Walktrap with increasing number of steps')
```

[image: walktrap, number of communities with increased step count]
[image: walktrap, size of largest community with increased step count]

Similarly with changing the gamma parameter for spinglass:

```
gamma <- c(0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.85, 1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 500.0)
sg <- list()
sgsize <- NULL

for(gm in gamma){
    cat(paste('Running spinglass with gamma =', gm, '\n'))
    sg0 <- spinglass.community(g, vertex = 1, gamma = gm)
    sgsize <- c(sgsize, length(sg0$community))
    sg[[as.character(gm)]] <- sg0
    }

plot(sgsize ~ log10(gamma),
    xlab = 'Gamma (log)',
    ylab = 'Size of the community',
    main = 'Spinglass with increasing value of gamma',
    xaxt = 'n'
    )
```

[image: spinglass, size of largest community with increasing gamma]

Another method `infomap`, according to its description is designed exactly to problems like yours. You may want to use not the igraph implementation, but the [original](http://www.mapequation.org/), as the latter gives more freedom in setting parameters. There are more Python implementations, but I don't know how flexible those are.

You can also try the [moduland](http://www.linkgroup.hu/modules.php) method family. Here you can chose between four landscape building method: nodeland, linkland, perturland and edgeweight; and two hill detection methods: total_hill and proportional_hill; in addition, at perturland you can set a parameter `x`. Please read the papers for more info. As I mentioned in a comment, you could inspect the affinities and set a threshold to select your core network. These methods have no Python interface, but you can simple export a text file and call the binaries by `subprocess`, and read their output back to Python.

For an overview of a large number of other methods [see here from page 52](http://www.linkgroup.hu/docs/ModuLand-ESM1-2010-06.pdf) ---this is already not up to date, but comprehensive.

Another idea is that you could run a number of methods, and comparing their results, find core network as a large partition delimited by cluster boundaries constant accross different methods. It is also a question how exact solution you need. Considering your data is quite noisy, likely you can expect thousands of nodes misclassified by any method. For a comparison of different clusterings, you could use something like normalized mutual information, which is implemented in igraph ([see more here](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~veronika/MAE/wagner07comparingclusterings.pdf).